# What are the best tools to schedule Snowflake tasks or python scripts in Ec2 to load data into snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-task

Please share your experiences wrt orchestrating jobs run through various tools and programmatic interfaces to load data to Snowflake-

1. python scripts in Ec2 instances. currently scheduled using crontab.
2. tasks in snowflake
3. Alteryx workflows

Are there any tools with sophisticated UI to create job workflows with dependencies?
The workflow can have -
python script followed by a task
Alteryx workflow followed by a python script and then a task

If any job fails then it should send emails to the team.

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have used both CONTROL-M and Apache Airflow to schedule and orchestrate data load to snowflake